# Spark flushing Dataframe on show / count

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to print the count of a dataframe, and then first few rows of it, before finally sending it out for further processing.

Strangely, after a call to `count()` the dataframe becomes empty.

```scala
val modifiedDF = funcA(sparkDF)
val deltaDF = modifiedDF.except(sparkDF)
```

```scala
println(deltaDF.count()) // prints 10
println(deltaDF.count())  //prints 0, similar behavior with show
```

```scala
funcB(deltaDF) //gets null dataframe
```

I was able to verify the same using `deltaDF.collect.foreach(println)` and subsequent calls to `count`.

However, if I do not call `count` or `show`, and just send it as is, `funcB` gets the whole DF with 10 rows.

Is it expected?

Definition of `funcA()` and its dependencies:

```scala
def funcA(inputDataframe: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val col_name = "colA"
    val modified_df = inputDataframe.withColumn(col_name, customUDF(col(col_name)))
    val modifiedDFRaw = modified_df.limit(10)
    modifiedDFRaw.withColumn("colA", modifiedDFRaw.col("colA").cast("decimal(38,10)"))
}


val customUDF = udf[Option[java.math.BigDecimal], java.math.BigDecimal](myUDF)


def myUDF(sval: java.math.BigDecimal): Option[java.math.BigDecimal] = {
        val strg_name = Option(sval).getOrElse(return None)
        if (change_cnt < 20)  { 
                    change_cnt = change_cnt + 1
                     Some(strg_name.multiply(new java.math.BigDecimal("1000")))
        } else {
            Some(strg_name)
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all function used as `UserDefinedFunction` has to be at least idempotent, but optimally pure. Otherwise the results are simply non-deterministic. While some escape hatch is provided in the latest versions (it is possible to hint Spark that function shouldn't be re-executed) these won't help you here.

Moreover having mutable stable (it is not exactly clear what is the source of `change_cnt`, but it is both written and read in the `udf`) as simply no go - Spark [doesn't provide global mutable state](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-).

Overall your code:

- Modifies some local copy of some object.
- Makes decision based on such object.

Unfortunately both components are simply not salvageable. You'll have to go back to planning phase and rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dataframe is a distributed dataset and trying to do a count() returns unpredictable results since the count() can be different in each node. Read the documentation about RDDs below. It is applicable to DataFrames as well.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd